# Is it possible to replicate a specific S3 folder between 2 buckets?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, replication

Does anyone know if it is possible to replicate just a folder of a bucket between 2 buckets using AWS S3 replication feature?

P.S.: I don't want to replicate the entire bucket, just one folder of the bucket.

If it is possible, what configurations I need to add to filter that folder in the replication?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Yes**. Amazon S3's Replication feature allows you to replicate objects at a prefix (say, folder) level from one S3 bucket to another within same region or across regions.

From the [AWS S3 Replication documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/replication-how-setup.html),

> The objects that you want to replicate — You can replicate all of the objects in the source bucket or a subset. You identify a subset by providing a key name prefix, one or more object tags, or both in the configuration.
>
> For example, if you configure a replication rule to replicate only objects with the key name prefix Tax/, Amazon S3 replicates objects with keys such as Tax/doc1 or Tax/doc2. But it doesn't replicate an object with the key Legal/doc3. If you specify both prefix and one or more tags, Amazon S3 replicates only objects having the specific key prefix and tags.

Refer to this [guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/enable-replication.html) on how to enable replication using AWS console. Step 4 talks about enabling replication at prefix level. The same can be done via [Cloudformation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/aws-properties-s3-bucket-replicationconfiguration-rules.html) and [CLI](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/s3api/put-bucket-replication.html) as well.

Comment: I have a similar use case , So the s3 bucket will have folders that will have files, the content of these folders should be copied to folder in buckets in other region. So what do you suggest? replication would fit in? what are the pros and cons here. The files would be coming every minute, lets assume 1 minute 1 file, or there can be 1000 files per hour, each file would be 300 MB, what would be the best solution in that case. Also with s3 replication can I delete the content that has been copied to other buckets ? requires encryption,version & copying every 15 minute would incur cost?

Comment: Replication is a perfect candidate for the usecase you have here. There are too many questions in a comment! Here is a [link](https://aws.amazon.com/s3/features/replication/?nc=sn&loc=2&dn=4) that should answer them.

Comment: But if the content has been deleted from source bucket will replication delete them in destination too

Comment: Yes, deleting an object will delete the replicated object too. But they are versioned, it would be delete marker instead of actual delete. You can recover it if you wish to.

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can do this using the Cross-Region Replication feature. You can replicate the object either in the same region or a different one. The replicated object in the new bucket will keep their original storage class, object name and object permissions. 
However, you can change the owner to the new owner of the destination bucket.

Despite all of this, there are disadvantages of this feature:-

- You cannot replicate objects which are     present in the source bucket 
  before you create the replication rule using CRR. Only the ones
  which    are created after replication rule can be created.
- You cannot use SSE-C encryption in replication.

Comment: Sorry but your answer is not clear for me, I want to replicate just a folder, not the entire bucket, is that possible and what configurations I need to do to filter just the folder that I want?

Comment: I'm not talking about the entire bucket. That's completely different. The above answer is for a folder or any data present in the bucket.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with sync command.

```
aws s3 sync s3://SOURCE_BUCKET_NAME s3://NEW_BUCKET_NAME
```

You must grant the destination account the permissions to perform the cross-account copy.

Comment: This is not active replication! Someone has to manually run this command or should have some automation in place to run this command on changes to the prefix.

Comment: My question was about replication, not sync feature.